# Combining multiple useState state values into another state value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've created two custom hooks `usePagination` and `useSearch`. These handle the logic for paging and searching and only expose getters/setters for the current page and search query.

Here's how I would use them in my list component:

```
const List = () => {
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = usePagination()
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useSearch()

  const queryParams = useMemo(() => ({
    page: currentPage,
    search: searchQuery
  }), [currentPage, searchQuery])

  // Pass the `queryParams` to an API endpoint to load my list items.
}
```

When the search query changes, I need to reset the current page to 1. Something like this:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  setCurrentPage(1)
}, [searchQuery, setCurrentPage])
```

Of course, with the above logic, this results in two API calls being made. One when the search query changes and then another immediately after when the current page value is reset.

Is there any way to combine the two values from my custom hooks `currentPage` and `searchQuery` into a combined state so that I can update both the page number and the query simultaneously? In other words, is there anything I can do here other than scrap my individual hooks and use a single state for everything?

E.g.

```
const [queryState, setQueryState] = useState({
  currentPage: 1,
  searchQuery: ""
})
```

Comment: What about using useRef for setCurrentPage?

Comment: @Arcanus - would you be able to provide an example of what that would look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and you almost got it right. You could do something like this:

```
const [queryState, setQueryState] = useState({
  currentPage: 1,
  searchQuery: ""
})

setQueryState((previousState) => {
  // change the state
  return previousState;
})
```

You could even wrap it into a hook that takes the initial state and returns the getter and a modified setter. Something like the following:

```
// hook body
const [queryState, setQueryState] = useState(initialState)

const modifiedSetter = (newValues) => {
 setQueryState((previousState) => {
    return {...previousState, ...newValues};
 })
}

return [queryState, modifiedSetter]
```

and the usage for it would be:

```
const [queryState, updateQuerySate] = useMyCustomHook({...someinitialState})

// Well, getter works the same: queryState.searchQuery

// but the setter goes like this

updateQuerySate({searchQuery: 'whatever'});
// or
updateQuerySate({searchQuery: 'whatever', currentPage: 1});
```

Comment: Thanks! That completely makes sense. However, imagine I have a lot of pagination-specific and search-specific logic in each hook - now I have to combine that into a single one. Furthermore, if I have certain components that only need search or paging, I can no longer include just the one hook. It's unfortunate but it seems like it's a limitation of React and I was curious if there are any alternative options.

Answer (score 1):

1. Can you explain why you need the setState/setCurrentPage function as a dependency?
2. As an intended effect, whenever a useState value changes the entire component is re-rendered, and that's why you have two API calls, because both states are causing a re-rendering.

Solution: Assuming you only want to make a new API call when searchQuery changes, and not when currentPage data changes, React provides useRef which you can use to store/update data ***without*** re-rendering and making costly API calls.

Example (in your usePagination hook):

```js
function usePagination() {
   const currentPage = useRef(0);
     
   //make API call...
   
   //if (currentPage.current === 0) {...}

   return currentPage
}
```

Then in List:

```js
const List = () => {
  const currentPage = usePagination()
  
  useEffect(()=>{
     currentPage.current = 1
  }, [searchQuery])

  //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense. I do need to fire off an API call when the `currentPage` changes so unfortunately `useRef` isn't viable for me. In my perfect world, I'd be able to continue using my individual hooks but I could somehow combine their states into a single state object.